# How to make interactive active line when clicked with react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have 3 lists of a clickable links, so when you click one you go to that section and the line too.

so this is my code :

```
<div className="description-container">
    <div className="nav-tab">
      <ul className="description-tab">
        <li>
          <a href="/" className="active">
            Class Description
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Testimony</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">FAQ</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How it looks like is
[image]

How I want is when I clicked Testimony, the line goes there and our page got scrolled into Testimony Section.

How to improve this code so I can get that feature with React?

Comment: You will need to use state and events. an onlick event on the a tags that sets a "selected" state. then change the class of the a tag if its the selected one